# How do I reduce the size of the header intro text and intro heading

Tags: html, css, fonts

How do I reduced the size of the text in the middle of that banner image? Whenever I reduce the font size, the photo goes above and the placement of the image is changed. I want to change the font size so that the text looks clean and on the right side and not overlapping with the person and also I want the tagline to look smaller than the header text.
I also want it to look cleaner on mobile devices. It was looking messy in the mobile browser

This is how it looks- https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPMtf.jpg

**HTML CODE**

```
 <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro-text">
                <div class="intro-lead-in">Welcome To AssignmentHelpStreet</div>
                <div class="intro-heading">The path you won't turn your back on</div>
                <a href="#about" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">About Us</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
header{
    background-image:url(../img/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center center;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    text-align:right;
    color:black;
}
header .intro-text{
    padding-top:100px;padding-bottom:50px
}
header .intro-text .intro-lead-in{
    font-family:"Droid Serif","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-style:italic;font-size:22px;line-height:22px;margin-bottom:25px
}
header .intro-text .intro-heading{
    font-family:Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:700;font-size:50px;line-height:50px;margin-bottom:25px
}
@media (min-width:768px){
    header .intro-text{
        padding-top:300px;padding-bottom:200px
    }
    header .intro-text .intro-lead-in{
        font-family:"Droid Serif","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-style:italic;font-size:40px;line-height:40px;margin-bottom:25px
    }
    header .intro-text .intro-heading{
        font-family:Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:700;font-size:75px;line-height:75px;margin-bottom:50px
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly which text size is to be reduced?

Comment: both the header text and the tagline. the "welcome to assignment help street" and also "the the path you won't turn your back on"

Comment: can u put the same image so that i help u in better way!

Comment: I didn't understand. Which image?

Comment: you can visit my website for a better view http://assignmenthelpstreet.com/

Comment: same background image which u have posted

Comment: can u post full code in codepen or jsbin or similar?

Comment: did you check the site?

Comment: yes..!!! i have checked it

Comment: so can you help me?

Comment: Can you help please?

Comment: can u post full code in codepen or jsbin or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of increasing the font size better to put image and text into the heading tags `<h2></h2>`, It will get increase the size of both

Comment: I want to decrease the font size, not increase. Decrease the size of header and tagline